# Play video from Folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to make a simple streaming site. That will pay a video from a folder. (mp4). The tricky part is I want to change the video everyday but not the code. So Im wondering if I can use some jquery or php for a global call to look in the folder find the file by the ext and play it.

So essentially instead of renaming the video or changing the codes specific path, I can just change the file thats in the folder, and refresh the page.

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NHyq.jpg)

Comment: yes you can do that, show us what you have tried and then we will help you out.

Comment: This is all I have so far

<video id="dep" class="center" width="900" height="720" controls>
  <source src="//FILE1/Redirected Folders/jbarfield/Desktop/Stream/depovideo" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  
<?php
foreach(glob('//FILE1/Redirected Folders/jbarfield/Desktop/Stream/depovideo*') as $video)
?>

Comment: Put that code in your question, not a comment please.

Comment: `glob` or `scandir` would tell you what's in the folders

Comment: depovideo is the folder that contains the .mp4

Comment: Find what's in the directory and play the latest file.

Comment: yeah thats what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, assuming there is only one video with the given extension in said folder (otherwise it will get the last occurring file with that extension):

```
$myVideoDir = '/videos';
$extension = 'mp4';
$videoFile = false;
foreach(scandir($myVideoDir) as $item) {
    if ( $item != '..' && $item != '.' && !is_dir($item) ) {
        $ext = preg_replace('#^.*\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$#', '$1', $item);
        if ( $ext == $extension )
            $videoFile = $item;
    }
}

if ( !!$videoFile ) {
    echo '
        <video id="dep" class="center" width="900" height="720" controls>        
          <source src="'.$myVideoDir.'/'.$videoFile.'" type="video/mp4"> 
        </video>
    ';
}
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks I'll try this

Comment: If my answer helped you please up vote it and check it as Answer. :)

Comment: Im seeing the end of the code on my webpage, '; } ?>

Comment: Can you post your entire code? It is working fine for me: http://codepad.org/8fDGW24E

Comment: You are trying to use your local filepath on codepad, that will not work.. Run this script on your server, but put die(print_r(scandir($myVideoDir), 1)); right before the foreach() loop and let me know what the output is. That way we can make sure it's finding the contents of the video directory properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myVideoDir = '/videos';
$extension = 'mp4';
$videoFile = false;
foreach(scandir($myVideoDir) as $item) {
    if ($item != '..' && $item != '.' && !is_dir($item)) {
        $ext = preg_replace('#^.*\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$#', '$1', $item);
        if ($ext == $extension) $videoFile = $item;
    }
}
if (!!$videoFile) {
    echo ' <video id="dep" class="center" width="900" height="720" controls> <source src="'.$myVideoDir.
    '/'.$videoFile.
    '" type="video/mp4"> </video> ';
}
```